# container not defined exception while working with google charts

Tags: javascript

I am getting the data from MySQL and want to display it in a line chart using google charts. I am using java and javascript.

**this is the type of data which i am getting from MySQL:**

**timestamp** 2017-06-12 19:22:23.0 , 2017-06-12 19:22:25.0
**f1** 414 413

I got this data in a resultset and converted it into JSONarray and the output is like: '[{"f1":414,"ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:23.0"},{"f1":415,"ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:25.0"}]'

-> from a servlet i am passing this string to a jsp file.

**

```js
<body>


<!-- header -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- header -->

<h1>welcome</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newstring =  <%= request.getAttribute("json_string")%>
<%System.out.println("value coming to jsp:  "+request.getAttribute("json_string"));%>
var chartData = JSON.parse(newstring);
</script>

<div id="curve_chart"></div>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
      
      


      for(i=0;i<chartData.length;i++)
       {
        var currentObj = chartData[i];
        document.write(currentObj.f1);
        document.write(currentObj.ts);
       }
        

      function drawChart() {
       var dTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       
    dTable.addColumn('string','timestamp'); 
    
    dTable.addColumn('number','f1');
    
    for(i=0;i<chartData.length;i++)
    {
     document.write("...inside for loop");
        var currentObj1 = chartData[i];
        dTable.addRow([currentObj1.ts,currentObj1.f1]);
      
    }

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        *var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));*

        chart.draw(dTable, options);
      }
    </script>

</body>
```

**

I am getting error in the line

**var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));**

and the error is : **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Container is not defined**

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go I have used google's example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).
Hope this helps

```js
var chartData = [
  {
    "f1":414,
    "ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:23.0"
   },
   {
    "f1":415,
    "ts":"2017-06-12 19:22:25.0"
   }
];

$(document).ready(() => {
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    // var data = [
    //   [
    //     'timestamp',
    //     'f1'
    //   ]
    // ];
    
    // chartData.forEach(item => {
    //   data.push([
    //     item.ts,
    //     item.f1
    //   ]);
    // });
    
    // var dTable = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
    
    var dTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dTable.addColumn('string', 'timestamp');
    dTable.addColumn('number', 'f1');
    
    dTable.addRows(chartData.map(item => {
      return [
        item.ts,
        item.f1
      ];
     }));
      
 
    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
      width: 400,
      height: 400
    };

    var chart = new google
      .visualization
      .LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

     chart.draw(dTable, options);
  }

});
```

```css
#curve_chart {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- header -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- header -->

<h1>welcome</h1>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks Vasile Florin Vilsan... It worked.. But still I have a question that how can we do it using DataTable() method instead of arrayToDataTable().

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you found this helpful don't forget to mark it as the answer to your problem.